# Actively monitor the modified date of all files in a directory

Tags: date, command

Is there a way to actively monitor the modified dates of all files or directories in a current directory?  I am using the BASH shell.

By actively I mean run a command once and then be able to monitor the changes of the time stamps as they change for each file *(similarly to how the `top` command shows you the active processes and only needs to be run once),* as opposed to manually running **`ls -lt`** many times and seeing what has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, `watch ls -lt` should do exactly what you want. With standard settings, it calls `ls -lt` every 2 seconds and shows the result. It has several interesting options, such as `watch -n 5 -d ls -lt`, which updates every 5 seconds (`-n 5`) and highlights the changes (`-d`).